# Battling to convert .ui to .py with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have been trying to convert my `.ui` to `.py` with `PyQt5` to no avail. I have made sure that the PATH has been set. The versions correspond. I have `PyQt5` for `Python` version `3.5`, and have `Python 3.5` installed.

I can see that the file is in my `/users/me/lib/site/packages/PyQt5/...` but for some reason I keep getting the same error. (Please see image attached).

Thanks in advance.

Image of convertions I have tried

[image]

Comment: Please if you have text to help us write it as text not unreadable pictures

Answer (score 0):

The error you show for each command is the same — it can't find your Python installation. It is saying `C:\Users\Lucien\python` doesn't exist because it's looking for `python`, hasn't found it in your path and assumes you meant it to be in the current folder.

What happens if you type `python` at the command line? Do you just have `py` available?

If `python` doesn't start Python, find your Python install location, find the `bin` folder containing the `python` executable and add that folder to your `PATH` in System properties.

Comment: Hi mfitzp. Thank you for your reply. I have checked the PATH for my python installation and it is there. If I just type python in the command line it launches python. But when I try to convert it gives the same error saying that python is not recognized.